# How can I input this formula into Wolfram alpha?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, wolframalpha

I want to use Wolfram Alpha to solve this question:

Expectation[ sqrt(x)/(sqrt(x)+ sqrt(y))] where x, y are uniformly distributed in [0,1].

I tried to translate this question into Wolfram alpha input window but failed.
Can you help me?

Comment: Can you adapt this `Integrate[ sqrt(x)/(sqrt(x)+ sqrt(y)), {x,0,1},{y,0,1}]` WolframAlpha input to solve your problem?